# I have to create an array with elements divided by 5

Tags: r, encoding, project

I have the current array
vecA=c(seq(10,100,2))
What I need to do is find the elements that are divided by 5 and create a new array with it.

Comment: When you say "are divided by 5", do you mean "are exactly divisible by 5"? Stated differently, are you looking for elements with modulus 5 = 0?

Comment: Yes I am looking for elements with modulus 5=0

Comment: Yes I have to wait 2 more minutes for that. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `%%` operator

```
vecB <- vecA[ vecA %% 5 == 0 ]
```