# How do I identify the position of elements in array?

Tags: r, project

I have the array vecA=c(seq(10,100,2))
I have to identify the positions of the elements that are exactly divisible by 3 and 4 and create a new array containing those elements.

Comment: this sounds an awful lot like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67012940/i-have-to-create-an-array-with-elements-divided-by-5 ... is there a course going on somewhere?

Comment: (you'd have to extend the answer slightly to `x %%3 | x %%4` (`|` means "or"))

Comment: It's a school project. 
I need to have the numbers divided by 3 and* 4, not by 3 or 4
Do you have any ideas for that?

Comment: well, if `x %% 3 == 0` means that `x` is a multiple of 3, and `x %% 4 == 0` means that it is (also) a multiple of 4, then perhaps instead of the "OR" `|` operator, you should use the "AND" `&` operator.